# EventLog - errors during write

Tags: c#, event-log

I use Event log like that:

```
if(!EventLog.SourceExists("Service"))
                EventLog.CreateEventSource("Service","Sending notification email error");
                EventLog.WriteEntry("Service",
                                    System.String.Format("Sending notification email error {0} \n {1} \n From {2} \n To {3} ",
                                    Error.Message,Error.StackTrace,From!=null?From.Address:"",
                                    To!=null?string.Join(",",To.ToList()):""),
                                    EventLogEntryType.Warning,2);
```

I have that code in two projects of same solution. But when I try to log information on production - one code log successfully, when other give me error

> The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched. Inaccessible logs: Security

I can not find what make a difference that other is not working :/

I do like on this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uksharepoint/archive/2009/10/19/using-custom-event-log-sources-on-least-privilege-sharepoint-servers.aspx) but i refer to .net 4.0 folder cause my app use .net4.

Any idea?

Comment: Do the two projects you are using the code run under different accounts as it seems that one of them does not have permissions to write to those logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be administrator to create an event log source. Do you have the correct rights?

Comment: Did you mean about this :HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Service  ?

Comment: Yes, If it fails to create it you can always create it manually

Comment: If weird but I have it created and it still failed.

Comment: In blog post i linked is says:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application and choose ‘export’ . I should add source in eventlog or in eventlog\Application folder? Now i have in eventlog only

Comment: @netmajor in the example the word application is essentially referring to YOURAPPNAME rather than an existing folder. You can export it from the server which is working as described in the article so yours would be HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Service

Comment: I set it in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Service and it work like charm ;)

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2awhba7a.aspx) says that `CreateEventSource` method may need some time to create the event source - that's why you should do it during instalation, to give the OS some time to set up the event source. Maybe that's the source of your problem.